# Viewpagers and Fragment Data Parsing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity having a view pager and in the Fragment i have a tablayout and putting the fragment in the tablayout without view pager. when binding the fragment to the viewpager and now swiping it changes the activity but not the fragment in the layout it shows empty.

```
tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.productdetail_tab);
replaceFragment(new ProductDetails());
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        switch(tab.getPosition()){
            case 0:
                replaceFragment(new ProductDetails());
                break;
            case 1:
                replaceFragment(new RelatedProducts());
                break;
        }
    }
});

public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
}
```

This below is adapter

```
public class ProductDetailsAdapterNew extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ProductDetailsAdapterNew(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {

            case 1: return new FragmentProductDetails();
            case 2: return new FragmentProductDetails2();
            case 3: return new FragmentProductDetails3();
            default: return new FragmentProductDetails();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Are you using tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);?